# Unable to change ui label in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parsing, uilabel

I am trying to make a weather app. the issue I am having is after I get the data parsed out I try to change the UILabel to equal the data that came back example.

```
if let weather = item["weather"] as? NSArray{
       if let value = weather[0] as? NSDictionary{
          if let description = value["description"] as? String{
                        print(description)
}
```

instead of printing the description I want to change the content of the UI Label like this

```
conditionlabel.text = description
```

but I get this error Reference to property 'Condition' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit.

however, every time I try the self. in front it does not print my data and something else happens. Any help would be much appreciated as I am new to this

Comment: "something else happens" - can you explain what exactly happens?

Comment: @koen instead of changing the UI Label to the response, for example (sunny...etc) it changes the label to display this <FireWeatherWatch.ViewController: 0x7fde57304660>. and when I print out to see if I can get more info it displays this in the debugger, Optional("<FireWeatherWatch.ViewController: 0x7fde57304660>") fire weather watch is the name of the app

Answer (score 1):

Create an optional variable in controller that has you UILabel:

```
var descriptionText: String?
```

Now when you parse data, assign value to this variable

```
if let description = value["description"] as? String{
                    descriptionText = description
}
```

After data is parsed assign this value to the label

```
self.conditionlabel.text = descriptionText
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do here is use `self.conditionlabel.text = description` (that is, the use of `self` is for the `UILabel` rather than `description` - my guess is that you were using `self.description` which gives you a description of the view controller.)

EDIT:
To overcome the threading issue, wrap the code like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.conditionlabel.text = description
}
```

Comment: when I do self I get this message "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only"

Comment: Please don’t suggest `[weak self]` in a DispatchQueue closure. It does not cause a retain cycle by design.

Comment: @vadian surely that's not the only thing to consider here - this question is for a weather app, which implies the data is coming over the network. It's possible that the view controller could be dismissed before the data is received, which would be a problem if the completion handler is captured by some static URL-related method.